# Animate resize of view during rotation without autoresize

Tags: iphone, ipad

If I set the AutoResize mask of my view, then they will resize together with the main window during device rotation.

Is there a way to get the same smooth performance by using my own animation and no autoresize?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can certainly use UIView animations to move elements around.

Also, a common technique is to hide the interface as part of

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

redraw it and show it as part of

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Here is an example:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    self.myTable.hidden = YES;
    ...
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [self redrawInterface];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    self.myTable.hidden = NO;
    ... 
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: To expand on this slightly; if you don't set animationDuration or animationCurve then you'll get the same defaults that are used for a rotation animation. It's not just hidden that you can change, it's any animatable property (to use the Apple term, to help with searching). Those include the frame/bounds and centre and the transform property. You can use the transform property to do any sort of translation, scale or rotation. Be careful though; the transform property hooks into the compositor (ie, the buffered versions of your views) rather than doing any on-CPU work.